# How to save 'true' and 'false' using Checkbox in Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to save 'true' and 'false' when Checkbox is checked or not respectively.This checkbox i have in one of the column of the kendo grid.But I am not able to do it.My code is as follows:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.Cashbox.HeaderkViewModel>()
    .Name("transactionGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

    columns.Bound(p => p.IsAllocatable).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Total Amount" }).Title("Total").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value='#=data.IsAllocatable#' class='IsAllocatable'  onclick='Allocatable(this)' />").Width(30);
    })
     .ToolBar(toolbar =>
         {
             //toolbar.Template("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext' onclick='customCommand()' href='#'></span>Cutom Command</a>");
             toolbar.Create();



             //toolbar.Save();
         })
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:280px;" })
.Navigatable()
.Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))                    //Having Different Template for New Dossier
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
        .PageSize(15)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.HeaderID);

    })

.Create(create => create.Action("Dossier_Create", "Dossier", new { @CompanyID = ViewBag.CompanyID }))
.Update(create => create.Action("Dossier_Create", "Dossier", new { @CompanyID = ViewBag.CompanyID }))
.Destroy(create => create.Action("Dossier_Create", "Dossier", new { @CompanyID = ViewBag.CompanyID }))


    )

        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))

    )

<script type="text/javascript">
function Allocatable(element) {
        if (element.checked) {
            element.value = 'true';
            var firstItem = $('#transactionGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[0];
            firstItem.set('IsAllocatable', true);
            if (element.value == true) { $(element).checked; }

        }
    }
</script>
```

try to help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are setting the value of the checkbox you are running into issues.  Think instead of saying data.IsAllocatable you should just write IsAllocatable, so like this:

```
.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value='#=IsAllocatable#'class='IsAllocatable'
onclick='Allocatable(this)' />").Width(30);
```

Comment: Thanks for Answering.This I have solved throuth the following ClientTemplate

Comment: .ClientTemplate(
    "<input type='checkbox'  ${ IsAllocated == true ? checked='checked' : ''}  value='#= IsAllocated#' onclick='Allocatable(this)'/>" +
    "<input type='hidden'  value='#= IsAllocated#' class='IsAllocated' />"
)